# jQuery effect not working for every div in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a webpage where initially every div element will be hidden.upon click on   particular element it will show the respective div and hide all other.

My code is working fine for the first two elements only,but not for all.
I am new to jQuery, and I am unable to find out what actually happening....
Thank You
for your reference here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>






<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  ($("body").children("div")).hide();

  ($("#cap1").click(function(){
   $("#cat3form1").toggle();
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form1").hide();}))

  ($("#cap2").click(function(){
   $("#cat3form2").toggle(); 
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form2").hide();}))

  ($("#cap3").click(function(){
  $("#cat3form3").toggle();
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form3").hide();}))

  ($("#cap4").click(function(){
  $("#cat3form4").toggle();
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form4").hide();}))

  ($("#cap5").click(function(){
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form5").hide();}))

  ($("#cap6").click(function(){
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form6").hide();}))

  ($("#cap7").click(function(){
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form7").hide();}))

  ($("#cap8").click(function(){
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form8").hide();}))
// $("#submitTooltip").mouseover(function() {
//     $("#submitTooltip" ).tooltip();})

// $("#proceedTooltip").click(function(){

// })
});
</script>










<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C|/Users/a/OneDrive/eGNIT/front-endSingleRowWithoutAdditionButtonModified/formStyle.css" />
<title>RESEARCH AND ACADEMIC CONTRIBUTIONS</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3 id="cap1"> Published Papers in Journals</h3>
<div id=cat3form1>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
      <th width="21%" scope="col">Title  with Page No.</th>
      <th width="9%" scope="col">Journal</th>
      <th width="14%" scope="col">ISSN/ISBN  No.</th>
      <th width="24%" scope="col">Whether  peer reviewed, impact factor, if any</th>
      <th width="13%" scope="col">No.  of co-authors</th>
      <th width="11%" scope="col">Whether  you are the main author</th>
      <th width="8%" scope="col"> Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="titleWithPage"></label>
      <input type="text" name="titleWithPage" id="titleWithPage" /></td>
      <td><label for="journal"></label>
      <input type="text" name="journal" id="journal" /></td>
      <td><label for="isbn"></label>
      <input type="text" name="isbn" id="isbn" /></td>
      <td><label for="peerReviewed"></label>
      <input type="text" name="peerReviewed" id="peerReviewed" /></td>
      <td><label for="coAuthorsNo"></label>
      <input type="text" name="coAuthorsNo" id="coAuthorsNo" /></td>
      <td><label for="mainAuthor"></label>
      <input type="text" name="mainAuthor" id="mainAuthor" /></td>
      <td id="journalScore"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>  
  </table>
 </div>

<h3 id="cap2">Articles / Chapters published in Books</h3>
<div id=cat3form2>
</form>
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
      <tr>
      <th scope="col">Title  with Page No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Book  Title, editor &amp; publisher</th>
      <th scope="col">ISSN/ISBN  No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Whether  peer reviewed</th>
      <th scope="col">No.  of co-authors</th>
      <th scope="col">Whether  you are the main author</th>
      <th scope="col">Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="titleWithPage"></label>
      <input type="text" name="titleWithPage" id="titleWithPage" /></td>
      <td><label for="bookDetail"></label>
      <input type="text" name="bookDetail" id="bookDetail" /></td>
      <td><label for="isbn"></label>
      <input type="text" name="isbn" id="isbn" /></td>
      <td><label for="peerReviewed"></label>
      <input type="text" name="peerReviewed" id="peerReviewed" /></td>
      <td><label for="coAuthorsNo"></label>
      <input type="text" name="coAuthorsNo" id="coAuthorsNo" /></td>
      <td><label for="mainAuthor"></label>
      <input type="text" name="mainAuthor" id="mainAuthor" /></td>
      <td id="publishedAricleScore"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

  </div>
  <h3 id="cap3">Full  Papers in Conference Proceedings</h3>

<div id= cat3form3>
</form>
<form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="t1">
      <tr>
      <th scope="col">Title  with Page No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Details  of Conference Publication</th>
      <th scope="col">ISSN/ISBN  No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Whether  peer reviewed</th>
      <th scope="col">No.  of co-authors</th>
      <th scope="col">Whether  you are the main author</th>
      <th scope="col">Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id=tr1>
      <td><label for="titleWithPage"></label>
      <input type="text" name="titleWithPage" id="titleWithPage" /></td>
      <td><label for="conferencePublication"></label>
      <input type="text" name="conferencePublication" id="conferencePublication" /></td>
      <td><label for="isbn"></label>
      <input type="text" name="isbn" id="isbn" /></td>
      <td><label for="peerReviewed"></label>
      <input type="text" name="peerReviewed" id="peerReviewed" /></td>
      <td><label for="coAuthorsNo"></label>
      <input type="text" name="coAuthorsNo" id="coAuthorsNo" /></td>
      <td><label for="mainAuthor"></label>
      <input type="text" name="mainAuthor" id="mainAuthor" /></td>
      <td id="fullPaperScore"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <input type="submit"  id="submitTooltip" title="click"/>
  <input type="button" formaction=""  value="submit and proceed to next form"  id="proceedTooltip"/>
</div>

<h3 id="cap4">Ongoing Projects / Consultancies</h3>

<div id=cat3form4>  
</form>
<form id="form4" name="form4" method="post" action="">

  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
      <tr>
      <th width="20%" scope="col">Title</th>
      <th width="20%" scope="col">Agency</th>
      <th width="19%" scope="col">Period</th>
      <th width="30%" scope="col"><p align="center">Grant/Amount  Mobilized(Rs.  Lakh)</p></th>
      <th width="11%" scope="col">Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="title"></label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" /></td>
      <td><label for="agency"></label>
      <input type="text" name="agency" id="agency" /></td>
      <td><label for="period"></label>
      <input type="text" name="period" id="period" /></td>
      <td><label for="grant"></label>
      <input type="text" name="grant" id="grant" /></td>
      <td id="ongoingProjectScore"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
<h3 id="cap5"> Completed Projects / Consultancies</h3>

<div id=cat3form5>
</form>
<form id="form5" name="form5" method="post" action="">

  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
      <tr>
      <th width="17%" scope="col">Title</th>
      <th width="17%" scope="col">Agency</th>
      <th width="13%" scope="col">Period</th>
      <th width="22%" scope="col"><p align="center">Grant/Amount  Mobilized(Rs.  Lakh)</p></th>
      <th width="23%" scope="col">Whether  policy document / patent as outcome</th>
      <th width="8%" scope="col">Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="title"></label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" /></td>
      <td><label for="agency"></label>
      <input type="text" name="agency" id="agency" /></td>
      <td><label for="period"></label>
      <input type="text" name="period" id="period" /></td>
      <td><label for="grant"></label>
      <input type="text" name="grant" id="grant" /></td>
      <td><label for="outcome"></label>
      <input type="text" name="outcome" id="outcome" /></td>
      <td id="completedProjectScore"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</form>

</div>
<h3 id="cap6">Research Guidance</h3>

<div id=cat3form6>
<form id="form6" name="form6" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <th width="29%" scope="col">Number  Enrolled</th>
    <th width="29%" scope="col">Thesis  Submitted</th>
    <th width="28%" scope="col">Degree  awarded</th>
    <th width="12%" scope="col">Score</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="numberEnrolled"></label>
      <input type="text" name="numberEnrolled" id="numberEnrolled" /></td>
    <td><label for="thesisiSubmitted"></label>
      <input type="text" name="thesisiSubmitted" id="thesisiSubmitted" /></td>
    <td><label for="degreeAwarded"></label>
      <input type="text" name="degreeAwarded" id="degreeAwarded" /></td>
    <td id="scoreResearchGuidance"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>

  </tr>

  </table>

</form>
</div>
<h3 id="cap7">Training Courses, Teaching-Learning-Evaluation Technology Programmes, Faculty Development Programmes / Refresher Course / QIP/ Summer School/ Orientation Programme (not less than one week duration)</h3>

<div id=cat3form7>
<form id="form7" name="form7" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Program</th>
      <th scope="col">Duration</th>
      <th scope="col">Organised By</th>
      <th scope="col">Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="programme"></label>
      <input type="text" name="programme" id="programme" /></td>
      <td><label for="duration"></label>
      <input type="text" name="duration" id="duration" /></td>
      <td><label for="organisedBy"></label>
      <input type="text" name="organisedBy" id="organisedBy" /></td>
      <td id="score"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</div>
<h3 id="cap8"> Papers presented in Conferences, Seminars, Workshops, Symposia</h3>

<div id=cat3form8>
<form id="form8" name="form8" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Title  of the paper presented</th>
      <th scope="col">Title  of Conference / Seminar</th>
      <th scope="col">Organised  by</th>
      <th scope="col">Whether  international / national / state / regional / College or University level</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="title"></label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" /></td>
      <td><label for="conferenceTitle"></label>
      <input type="text" name="conferenceTitle" id="conferenceTitle" /></td>
      <td><label for="organisedBy"></label>
      <input type="text" name="organisedBy" id="organisedBy" /></td>
      <td><label for="level"></label>
      <input type="text" name="level" id="level" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: provide fiddle rather than posting so much code

Comment: Since all jquery code seems the same, I can only presume some ID in your HTML is broken. So, without seing your HTML I can only presume its a selector issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try below jquery : Use **[Start with Jquery Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** and hide all elements whose id start with `cat3form` and bind click event for all `h3` whose id starts with `cap`

```
$(function(){
  // hide all cat3form div
  $('div[id^="cat3form"]').hide();

  //bind click event
    $('h3[id^="cap"]').click(function(){
    $(this).next('div[id^="cat3form"]').toggle();

    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/38Qq8/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>






<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  ($("body").children("div")).hide();

  $("#cap1").click(function(){
   $("#cat3form1").toggle();
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form1").hide();})

  $("#cap2").click(function(){
   $("#cat3form2").toggle(); 
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form2").hide();})

  $("#cap3").click(function(){
  $("#cat3form3").toggle();
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form3").hide();})

  $("#cap4").click(function(){
  $("#cat3form4").toggle();
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form4").hide();})

  $("#cap5").click(function(){
  $("#cat3form5").toggle();
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form5").hide();})

  $("#cap6").click(function(){
  $("#cat3form6").toggle();
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form6").hide();})

  $("#cap7").click(function(){
  $("#cat3form7").toggle();
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form7").hide();})

  $("#cap8").click(function(){
  $("#cat3form8").toggle();
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form8").hide();})
// $("#submitTooltip").mouseover(function() {
//     $("#submitTooltip" ).tooltip();})

// $("#proceedTooltip").click(function(){

// })
});
</script>










<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C|/Users/a/OneDrive/eGNIT/front-endSingleRowWithoutAdditionButtonModified/formStyle.css" />
<title>RESEARCH AND ACADEMIC CONTRIBUTIONS</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3 id="cap1"> Published Papers in Journals</h3>
<div id=cat3form1>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
      <th width="21%" scope="col">Title  with Page No.</th>
      <th width="9%" scope="col">Journal</th>
      <th width="14%" scope="col">ISSN/ISBN  No.</th>
      <th width="24%" scope="col">Whether  peer reviewed, impact factor, if any</th>
      <th width="13%" scope="col">No.  of co-authors</th>
      <th width="11%" scope="col">Whether  you are the main author</th>
      <th width="8%" scope="col"> Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="titleWithPage"></label>
      <input type="text" name="titleWithPage" id="titleWithPage" /></td>
      <td><label for="journal"></label>
      <input type="text" name="journal" id="journal" /></td>
      <td><label for="isbn"></label>
      <input type="text" name="isbn" id="isbn" /></td>
      <td><label for="peerReviewed"></label>
      <input type="text" name="peerReviewed" id="peerReviewed" /></td>
      <td><label for="coAuthorsNo"></label>
      <input type="text" name="coAuthorsNo" id="coAuthorsNo" /></td>
      <td><label for="mainAuthor"></label>
      <input type="text" name="mainAuthor" id="mainAuthor" /></td>
      <td id="journalScore"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>  
  </table>
 </div>
</form>
<h3 id="cap2">Articles / Chapters published in Books</h3>
<div id=cat3form2>

<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
      <tr>
      <th scope="col">Title  with Page No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Book  Title, editor &amp; publisher</th>
      <th scope="col">ISSN/ISBN  No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Whether  peer reviewed</th>
      <th scope="col">No.  of co-authors</th>
      <th scope="col">Whether  you are the main author</th>
      <th scope="col">Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="titleWithPage"></label>
      <input type="text" name="titleWithPage" id="titleWithPage" /></td>
      <td><label for="bookDetail"></label>
      <input type="text" name="bookDetail" id="bookDetail" /></td>
      <td><label for="isbn"></label>
      <input type="text" name="isbn" id="isbn" /></td>
      <td><label for="peerReviewed"></label>
      <input type="text" name="peerReviewed" id="peerReviewed" /></td>
      <td><label for="coAuthorsNo"></label>
      <input type="text" name="coAuthorsNo" id="coAuthorsNo" /></td>
      <td><label for="mainAuthor"></label>
      <input type="text" name="mainAuthor" id="mainAuthor" /></td>
      <td id="publishedAricleScore"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

  </div>
</form>
  <h3 id="cap3">Full  Papers in Conference Proceedings</h3>

<div id= cat3form3>

<form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="t1">
      <tr>
      <th scope="col">Title  with Page No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Details  of Conference Publication</th>
      <th scope="col">ISSN/ISBN  No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Whether  peer reviewed</th>
      <th scope="col">No.  of co-authors</th>
      <th scope="col">Whether  you are the main author</th>
      <th scope="col">Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id=tr1>
      <td><label for="titleWithPage"></label>
      <input type="text" name="titleWithPage" id="titleWithPage" /></td>
      <td><label for="conferencePublication"></label>
      <input type="text" name="conferencePublication" id="conferencePublication" /></td>
      <td><label for="isbn"></label>
      <input type="text" name="isbn" id="isbn" /></td>
      <td><label for="peerReviewed"></label>
      <input type="text" name="peerReviewed" id="peerReviewed" /></td>
      <td><label for="coAuthorsNo"></label>
      <input type="text" name="coAuthorsNo" id="coAuthorsNo" /></td>
      <td><label for="mainAuthor"></label>
      <input type="text" name="mainAuthor" id="mainAuthor" /></td>
      <td id="fullPaperScore"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <input type="submit"  id="submitTooltip" title="click"/>
  <input type="button" formaction=""  value="submit and proceed to next form"  id="proceedTooltip"/>
</div>
</form>
<h3 id="cap4">Ongoing Projects / Consultancies</h3>

<div id=cat3form4>  

<form id="form4" name="form4" method="post" action="">

  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
      <tr>
      <th width="20%" scope="col">Title</th>
      <th width="20%" scope="col">Agency</th>
      <th width="19%" scope="col">Period</th>
      <th width="30%" scope="col"><p align="center">Grant/Amount  Mobilized(Rs.  Lakh)</p></th>
      <th width="11%" scope="col">Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="title"></label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" /></td>
      <td><label for="agency"></label>
      <input type="text" name="agency" id="agency" /></td>
      <td><label for="period"></label>
      <input type="text" name="period" id="period" /></td>
      <td><label for="grant"></label>
      <input type="text" name="grant" id="grant" /></td>
      <td id="ongoingProjectScore"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
</form>
<h3 id="cap5"> Completed Projects / Consultancies</h3>

<div id=cat3form5>

<form id="form5" name="form5" method="post" action="">

  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
      <tr>
      <th width="17%" scope="col">Title</th>
      <th width="17%" scope="col">Agency</th>
      <th width="13%" scope="col">Period</th>
      <th width="22%" scope="col"><p align="center">Grant/Amount  Mobilized(Rs.  Lakh)</p></th>
      <th width="23%" scope="col">Whether  policy document / patent as outcome</th>
      <th width="8%" scope="col">Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="title"></label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" /></td>
      <td><label for="agency"></label>
      <input type="text" name="agency" id="agency" /></td>
      <td><label for="period"></label>
      <input type="text" name="period" id="period" /></td>
      <td><label for="grant"></label>
      <input type="text" name="grant" id="grant" /></td>
      <td><label for="outcome"></label>
      <input type="text" name="outcome" id="outcome" /></td>
      <td id="completedProjectScore"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</form>

</div>
<h3 id="cap6">Research Guidance</h3>

<div id=cat3form6>
<form id="form6" name="form6" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <th width="29%" scope="col">Number  Enrolled</th>
    <th width="29%" scope="col">Thesis  Submitted</th>
    <th width="28%" scope="col">Degree  awarded</th>
    <th width="12%" scope="col">Score</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="numberEnrolled"></label>
      <input type="text" name="numberEnrolled" id="numberEnrolled" /></td>
    <td><label for="thesisiSubmitted"></label>
      <input type="text" name="thesisiSubmitted" id="thesisiSubmitted" /></td>
    <td><label for="degreeAwarded"></label>
      <input type="text" name="degreeAwarded" id="degreeAwarded" /></td>
    <td id="scoreResearchGuidance"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>

  </tr>

  </table>

</form>
</div>
<h3 id="cap7">Training Courses, Teaching-Learning-Evaluation Technology Programmes, Faculty Development Programmes / Refresher Course / QIP/ Summer School/ Orientation Programme (not less than one week duration)</h3>

<div id=cat3form7>
<form id="form7" name="form7" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Program</th>
      <th scope="col">Duration</th>
      <th scope="col">Organised By</th>
      <th scope="col">Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="programme"></label>
      <input type="text" name="programme" id="programme" /></td>
      <td><label for="duration"></label>
      <input type="text" name="duration" id="duration" /></td>
      <td><label for="organisedBy"></label>
      <input type="text" name="organisedBy" id="organisedBy" /></td>
      <td id="score"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</div>
<h3 id="cap8"> Papers presented in Conferences, Seminars, Workshops, Symposia</h3>

<div id=cat3form8>
<form id="form8" name="form8" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Title  of the paper presented</th>
      <th scope="col">Title  of Conference / Seminar</th>
      <th scope="col">Organised  by</th>
      <th scope="col">Whether  international / national / state / regional / College or University level</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="title"></label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" /></td>
      <td><label for="conferenceTitle"></label>
      <input type="text" name="conferenceTitle" id="conferenceTitle" /></td>
      <td><label for="organisedBy"></label>
      <input type="text" name="organisedBy" id="organisedBy" /></td>
      <td><label for="level"></label>
      <input type="text" name="level" id="level" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Try This It Will Work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>






<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  ($("body").children("div")).hide();

  ($("#cap1").click(function(){
   $("#cat3form1").toggle();
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form1").hide();}));

  ($("#cap2").click(function(){
   $("#cat3form2").toggle(); 
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form2").hide();}));

  ($("#cap3").click(function(){
      alert("cap3");
  $("#cat3form3").toggle();
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form3").hide();}));

  ($("#cap4").click(function(){
  $("#cat3form4").toggle();
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form4").hide();}));

  ($("#cap5").click(function(){
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form5").hide();}));

  ($("#cap6").click(function(){
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form6").hide();}));

  ($("#cap7").click(function(){
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form7").hide();}));

  ($("#cap8").click(function(){
  ($("body").children("div")).not("#cat3form8").hide();}));
// $("#submitTooltip").mouseover(function() {
//     $("#submitTooltip" ).tooltip();})

// $("#proceedTooltip").click(function(){

// })
});
</script>










<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C|/Users/a/OneDrive/eGNIT/front-endSingleRowWithoutAdditionButtonModified/formStyle.css" />
<title>RESEARCH AND ACADEMIC CONTRIBUTIONS</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3 id="cap1"> Published Papers in Journals</h3>
<div id=cat3form1>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
      <th width="21%" scope="col">Title  with Page No.</th>
      <th width="9%" scope="col">Journal</th>
      <th width="14%" scope="col">ISSN/ISBN  No.</th>
      <th width="24%" scope="col">Whether  peer reviewed, impact factor, if any</th>
      <th width="13%" scope="col">No.  of co-authors</th>
      <th width="11%" scope="col">Whether  you are the main author</th>
      <th width="8%" scope="col"> Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="titleWithPage"></label>
      <input type="text" name="titleWithPage" id="titleWithPage" /></td>
      <td><label for="journal"></label>
      <input type="text" name="journal" id="journal" /></td>
      <td><label for="isbn"></label>
      <input type="text" name="isbn" id="isbn" /></td>
      <td><label for="peerReviewed"></label>
      <input type="text" name="peerReviewed" id="peerReviewed" /></td>
      <td><label for="coAuthorsNo"></label>
      <input type="text" name="coAuthorsNo" id="coAuthorsNo" /></td>
      <td><label for="mainAuthor"></label>
      <input type="text" name="mainAuthor" id="mainAuthor" /></td>
      <td id="journalScore"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>  
  </table>
 </div>

<h3 id="cap2">Articles / Chapters published in Books</h3>
<div id=cat3form2>
</form>
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
      <tr>
      <th scope="col">Title  with Page No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Book  Title, editor &amp; publisher</th>
      <th scope="col">ISSN/ISBN  No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Whether  peer reviewed</th>
      <th scope="col">No.  of co-authors</th>
      <th scope="col">Whether  you are the main author</th>
      <th scope="col">Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="titleWithPage"></label>
      <input type="text" name="titleWithPage" id="titleWithPage" /></td>
      <td><label for="bookDetail"></label>
      <input type="text" name="bookDetail" id="bookDetail" /></td>
      <td><label for="isbn"></label>
      <input type="text" name="isbn" id="isbn" /></td>
      <td><label for="peerReviewed"></label>
      <input type="text" name="peerReviewed" id="peerReviewed" /></td>
      <td><label for="coAuthorsNo"></label>
      <input type="text" name="coAuthorsNo" id="coAuthorsNo" /></td>
      <td><label for="mainAuthor"></label>
      <input type="text" name="mainAuthor" id="mainAuthor" /></td>
      <td id="publishedAricleScore"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

  </div>
  <h3 id="cap3">Full  Papers in Conference Proceedings</h3>

<div id= cat3form3>
</form>
<form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="t1">
      <tr>
      <th scope="col">Title  with Page No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Details  of Conference Publication</th>
      <th scope="col">ISSN/ISBN  No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Whether  peer reviewed</th>
      <th scope="col">No.  of co-authors</th>
      <th scope="col">Whether  you are the main author</th>
      <th scope="col">Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id=tr1>
      <td><label for="titleWithPage"></label>
      <input type="text" name="titleWithPage" id="titleWithPage" /></td>
      <td><label for="conferencePublication"></label>
      <input type="text" name="conferencePublication" id="conferencePublication" /></td>
      <td><label for="isbn"></label>
      <input type="text" name="isbn" id="isbn" /></td>
      <td><label for="peerReviewed"></label>
      <input type="text" name="peerReviewed" id="peerReviewed" /></td>
      <td><label for="coAuthorsNo"></label>
      <input type="text" name="coAuthorsNo" id="coAuthorsNo" /></td>
      <td><label for="mainAuthor"></label>
      <input type="text" name="mainAuthor" id="mainAuthor" /></td>
      <td id="fullPaperScore"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <input type="submit"  id="submitTooltip" title="click"/>
  <input type="button" value="submit and proceed to next form"  id="proceedTooltip"/>
</div>

<h3 id="cap4">Ongoing Projects / Consultancies</h3>

<div id=cat3form4>  
</form>
<form id="form4" name="form4" method="post" action="">

  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
      <tr>
      <th width="20%" scope="col">Title</th>
      <th width="20%" scope="col">Agency</th>
      <th width="19%" scope="col">Period</th>
      <th width="30%" scope="col"><p align="center">Grant/Amount  Mobilized(Rs.  Lakh)</p></th>
      <th width="11%" scope="col">Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="title"></label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" /></td>
      <td><label for="agency"></label>
      <input type="text" name="agency" id="agency" /></td>
      <td><label for="period"></label>
      <input type="text" name="period" id="period" /></td>
      <td><label for="grant"></label>
      <input type="text" name="grant" id="grant" /></td>
      <td id="ongoingProjectScore"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
<h3 id="cap5"> Completed Projects / Consultancies</h3>

<div id=cat3form5>
</form>
<form id="form5" name="form5" method="post" action="">

  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
      <tr>
      <th width="17%" scope="col">Title</th>
      <th width="17%" scope="col">Agency</th>
      <th width="13%" scope="col">Period</th>
      <th width="22%" scope="col"><p align="center">Grant/Amount  Mobilized(Rs.  Lakh)</p></th>
      <th width="23%" scope="col">Whether  policy document / patent as outcome</th>
      <th width="8%" scope="col">Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="title"></label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" /></td>
      <td><label for="agency"></label>
      <input type="text" name="agency" id="agency" /></td>
      <td><label for="period"></label>
      <input type="text" name="period" id="period" /></td>
      <td><label for="grant"></label>
      <input type="text" name="grant" id="grant" /></td>
      <td><label for="outcome"></label>
      <input type="text" name="outcome" id="outcome" /></td>
      <td id="completedProjectScore"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</form>

</div>
<h3 id="cap6">Research Guidance</h3>

<div id=cat3form6>
<form id="form6" name="form6" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <th width="29%" scope="col">Number  Enrolled</th>
    <th width="29%" scope="col">Thesis  Submitted</th>
    <th width="28%" scope="col">Degree  awarded</th>
    <th width="12%" scope="col">Score</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="numberEnrolled"></label>
      <input type="text" name="numberEnrolled" id="numberEnrolled" /></td>
    <td><label for="thesisiSubmitted"></label>
      <input type="text" name="thesisiSubmitted" id="thesisiSubmitted" /></td>
    <td><label for="degreeAwarded"></label>
      <input type="text" name="degreeAwarded" id="degreeAwarded" /></td>
    <td id="scoreResearchGuidance"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>

  </tr>

  </table>

</form>
</div>
<h3 id="cap7">Training Courses, Teaching-Learning-Evaluation Technology Programmes, Faculty Development Programmes / Refresher Course / QIP/ Summer School/ Orientation Programme (not less than one week duration)</h3>

<div id=cat3form7>
<form id="form7" name="form7" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Program</th>
      <th scope="col">Duration</th>
      <th scope="col">Organised By</th>
      <th scope="col">Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="programme"></label>
      <input type="text" name="programme" id="programme" /></td>
      <td><label for="duration"></label>
      <input type="text" name="duration" id="duration" /></td>
      <td><label for="organisedBy"></label>
      <input type="text" name="organisedBy" id="organisedBy" /></td>
      <td id="score"><input name="score" type="text" id="score" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</div>
<h3 id="cap8"> Papers presented in Conferences, Seminars, Workshops, Symposia</h3>

<div id=cat3form8>
<form id="form8" name="form8" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Title  of the paper presented</th>
      <th scope="col">Title  of Conference / Seminar</th>
      <th scope="col">Organised  by</th>
      <th scope="col">Whether  international / national / state / regional / College or University level</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="title"></label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" /></td>
      <td><label for="conferenceTitle"></label>
      <input type="text" name="conferenceTitle" id="conferenceTitle" /></td>
      <td><label for="organisedBy"></label>
      <input type="text" name="organisedBy" id="organisedBy" /></td>
      <td><label for="level"></label>
      <input type="text" name="level" id="level" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

`div {
    display: hidden;
}`

Javascript:

`$("#cap1").click(function() {
    $("#cat3form1").show();
    $("div:not(#cat3form1)").hide();
});`

OR

`$("div").hide();
$("#cat3form1").show();`

Not tested. But you know what i meant here. Questions in comment

Answer (score 0):

this code us used to hide all div accept one which is on clicked.

```
$("div").click(function(){
 ($("body").children("div")).hide();
  $(this).toggle();
  $(this).show();
});
```

we don't need repetitive code for all div.